# How do I average column values from a tab-separated data file, ignoring a header row and the left column?

Tags: perl, strict

My task is to compute averages from the following data file, titled `Lab1_table.txt`:

```
retrovirus      genome  gag     pol     env
HIV-1           9181    1503    3006    2571
FIV             9474    1353    2993    2571
KoRV            8431    1566    3384    1980
GaLV            8088    1563    3498    2058
PERV            8072    1560    3621    1532
```

I have to write a script that will open and read this file, read each line by splitting the contents into an array and computer the average of the numerical values (`genome`, `gag`, `pol`, `env`), and write to a new file the average from each of the aforementioned columns.

I've been trying my best to figure out how to not take into account the first row, or the first column, but every time I try to execute on the command line I keep coming up with 'explicit package name' errors.

```
Global symbol @average requires explicit package name at line 23.
Global symbol @average requires explicit package name at line 29.
Execution aborted due to compilation errors.
```

I understand that this involves `@` and `$`, but even knowing that I've not been able to change the errors.

This is my code, but I emphasise that I'm a beginner having started this just last week:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;

my $infile = "Lab1_table.txt"; # This is the file path
open INFILE, $infile or die "Can't open $infile: $!";

my $count = 0;
my $average = ();

while (<INFILE>) {
    chomp;
    my @columns = split /\t/;
    $count++;
    if ( $count == 1 ) {
        $average = @columns;
    }
    else {
        for( my $i = 1; $i < scalar $average; $i++ )  {
            $average[$i] += $columns[$i];
        }
    }
}

for( my $i = 1; $i < scalar $average; $i++ ) {
    print $average[$i]/$count, "\n";
}
```

I'd appreciate any insight, and I would also great appreciate letting me know by list numbering what you're doing at each step - if appropriate. I'd like to learn and it would make more sense to me if I was able to read through what someone's process was.

Comment: ok, I see you've taken to heart the `use warnings` and `use strict` commandments. And that's where your error is coming from. You declared 'average' to be an array ref (kinda) then you used it as an array.
try one or the other (but NOT both) of these:
1. change line to be @average OR 2. dereference properly with `$average->[i]`
Note, this won't solve the whole problem, but it will get rid of the error messages for you, allowing you to focus on the logic.

Comment: Oh, I just had to dereference it. That did get rid of the last two errors, and you're right it doesn't solve the whole problem as I come up with this now: Can't use string ("5") as an ARRAY ref while "strict refs" in use at line 23, <INFILE> line 2.

I'm unsurewhat's happened here though...

Comment: @PkC you may want to update your code sample to display the latest state of your code.  That would be more helpful for debugging.

Comment: @PkC and provide sample output based on the input. Welcome to SO.

Comment: @Oalders - Thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately, for some reason, my Command Prompt doesn't want to run perl at home, although it works at University for some reason. I'm not sure why, but it keeps coming up with: 'perl' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file. This comes up even though I loaded up the .bat file (same one that does work at University). I also restarted the computer, to no avail.

I also tried out not using 'perl' followed by my .pl file, and that just came up with a dialogue saying 'choose program to open with...'

Comment: I think I'll probably have to either work on this tomorrow when I'm back at University, or try and find an alternative to cmd to use at home, in order to execute the script. Only then I'll be able to know what's going on! I'm really sorry, I feel like a complete dumbo here.

As soon as I can get around to working around on it, I will provide an updated script. Also @Jchips12 - Thank you for your response also. It looks helpful already, and thank you for keeping it within limits I can understand. That will help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are the points you need to change
Use another variable for the headers

```
my $count = 0;
my @header = ();
my @average = ();
```

then change the logic inside if statement

```
if ( $count == 1 ) {
    @header = @columns;
}
```

Now don't use the `@average` for the limit, use `$i < scalar @columns` for else statement.
Initially `@average` is zero, you will never get inside the for loop ever.

```
else {
    for( my $i = 1; $i < scalar @columns; $i++ )  {
        $average[$i] += $columns[$i];
    }
}
```

Finally add `-1` to your counter. Remember you increment your counter when you parse your header

```
for( my $i = 1; $i < scalar @average; $i++ ) {
    print $average[$i]/($count-1), "\n";
}
```

Here is the final code
You can take advantage of `@header` to display the result neatly

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use strict;

my $infile = "Lab1_table.txt"; # This is the file path
open INFILE, $infile or die "Can't open $infile: $!"; 

my $count = 0;
my @header = ();
my @average = ();

while (<INFILE>) {
    chomp;


    my @columns = split /\t/;
    $count++;
    if ( $count == 1 ) {
        @header = @columns;
    }
    else {
        for( my $i = 1; $i < scalar @columns; $i++ )  {
            $average[$i] += $columns[$i];
        }
    }
} 

for( my $i = 1; $i < scalar @average; $i++ ) {
    print $average[$i]/($count-1), "\n";
}
```

There are other ways to write this code but I thought it would be better to just correct your code so that you can easily understand what is wrong with your code. Hope it helps

Comment: I just wanted to thank you considerably for this. I really do. It works perfectly and I can see the right averages. 0 for the first column, and the other ones are regarded as 'header'.

Comment: I've now created an 'outfile' action, so that I can print the results to a text file. The .txt file is produced, but no text is within it.

First, the output I get from my amended script comes out with this statement:
'code' Argument "" isn't numeric in ddition (+) at line X, <INFILE> line Y.'code'

The above occurs 5 times, and I presume this is due to the non-numerical headers in my source file (as noted in my above comment).

This is followed then by '0' (which I presume is the first column), and then the 4 required averages.

I just can't seem to print to file, for some reason.

Comment: It would be better if you create another question for that.

Comment: Sure thing, I've just posted one now. I'll also be posting something about another task I wanted to understand also, but I have to wait to post that one! :)